# Android - Why do location services not work using restricted profile?

Tags: service, geolocation, location

I am creating a mobile app using Appcelerator that uses Geolocation to get coordinates at specific times based on user action.  On iOS it works perfectly, and on Android it works perfectly but only when logged in as the owner of the device, NOT when logged in under a restricted profile.  When logged in under the restricted profile one of two errors occur: 1) location is currently available or 2) Can't access current location.  I've made sure that the location services are turned on under the restricted profile.

Here is the uses-permission section of the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

Here is the Geolocation function I am using:

```
    if (Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled == true)
    {
        if (platform == 'android')
        {
            Titanium.Geolocation.Android.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_HIGH;
        }
        else
        {
            Titanium.Geolocation.accuracy = Titanium.Geolocation.ACCURACY_HIGH;
        }
        Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesAuthorization = Titanium.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE;
        Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 5;
        Titanium.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Titanium.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;

        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
            clearTimeout(timer2);
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                if (!e.success || e.error)
                {
                    alert('Error: ' + e.error);
                    //alert('An error occured getting your location.  Please close and try again.');
                    return;
                }
                currLongitude = e.coords.longitude;
                currLatitude = e.coords.latitude;
                CheckSave();
            }, 2000);
        });
    }   
    else
    {
        alert('Please enable location services.');
    }
```

I am using a setTimer in the getCurrentPosition to give the device enough time to get the coordinates.  Again, the only issue I'm having is using the app on an Android device logged in under a restricted profile.  What can be done about this?  Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: Found the  issue and resolution.  Issue: I installed under the owner profile and used the app testing functionality, then switched to the restricted profile.  Data that had been stored during use under the owner profile still existed.  Resolution:  Clear data on the app under the RESTRICTED profile and run the app...problem solved!  Hope this helps someone else out cause this plagued me for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue and resolution. Issue: I installed under the owner profile and used the app testing functionality, then switched to the restricted profile. Data that had been stored during use under the owner profile still existed. Resolution: Clear data on the app under the RESTRICTED profile and run the app...problem solved! Hope this helps someone else out cause this plagued me for 3 days.